# how do i get the website in json format?

Tags: android, json

i need to get a website (any website ) in json format to use it with android and json parser to get data and if possible that the website include images to be able to download data and images using json parser.
i have been searching about 2 days without any success, its my first time that i use json so i do know where to search and how to search.

what i need is a website to make a test on it that will be available in json format

anyone can help me ???

i will appreciate that.

Comment: JSOUP..idk whether it can help or not but worth try..http://jsoup.org/

Comment: There are tons of example available in internet. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ is one of the nice one.

Comment: @ Spring Breaker that is  not what i asked for   ... i need  URL of website that can be available in json format that all what i want ... i dont want website that include tutorials and example about JSON

Comment: @user3006788:Inside that tutorial you will get the url dude, just go through that.

Comment: i saw this tutorial and i want other websites that are available in json format is there any way to find these websites ? and how to find it ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`http://www.jsontest.com/`](http://www.jsontest.com/) to get `JSON` from that website.

Read there and for example if you call `http://ip.jsontest.com/` you will get a JSON response as `{"ip": "203.92.62.242"}` then you can parse them in your android application.

Comment: @ JJPA  so to understand your answer  correctly...  if i put any website URL + **jsontest.com** i will get the json format of this website ??? can you explain more your answer please??

Comment: You don't really need a whole website thats is in JSON format but the content from a server with JSON format. Once you get that you can parse them and display it. The URL's provided in that site will provide you different JSON formats.

Comment: so if i want i json format of data that include also images how to get that ????   because until now i did not understand how to search for the json format of any website  to be able to parse it with android

Comment: Use http://echo.jsontest.com/somedata/insert-value-here/someimage/urlofimagehere to get json with image link also. Now replace urlofimagehere  with a proper url which has an image

Comment: annn so it is not i must that the website iclude data and images i can get the data from a website and add images from other website either if it is from another website ?? i asked to much because it my first time using json

Comment: Yes that site provides you only JSON. you have to include data.

Answer (score 0):

**For future readers :**

Facebook programmers provide the json format for each request.

**All you have to do is :**

If the facebook page url is : http://www.facebook.com/youtube

To get json format of page, request this : http://graph.facebook.com/youtube

**I suggest to read that :**

Usually standard web service today provide data in at least two format: json and xml for each endpoint (url), you just add .xml or .json extension to the requested url.

But most of the time you don't have to do that, common web services today always provide json data because it's defined in RESTFul rules. If they dont, you can't get the json. The case is same for you, just ask the developer for API docs.